# URL based modal in react-router V4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to accomplish this modal:

[image]

I want to render my image gallery, and when clicking on an image, the popup needs to be opened.
I want to do it with urls and not with state/store changes.
for example:

the link : "/gallery/popular/fhoeuwy3928" will render the gallery in the back and the popup in front.

In react-router 3 it was simple with nested routes. How can I do it with v4?

These are my current routes:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
<Route path='/gallery/:category' component={Gallery}/>
<Route path='/gallery/:category/:id' component={Popup}/>
```

Comment: Is there any issues at the moment? Also, can you show the Popup componenet Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, This is how I arranged the routes eventually:

MainView.js

```
 <Switch>
    <Route path='/gallery/:category' component={Gallery} /> 
 </Switch>
```

Gallery.js

```
  <Switch>
     <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/:id`} component={Popup} />
  </Switch>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a good example here, in `React Router v4` docs https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery

It well explained there, but anyway - the main thing there `<Switch>` component, if image opened in modal will keep `location` property the same, while we could open our modal "window" in case if it needed or we not outputing anything:

`{isModal ? <Route path='/img/:id' component={Modal} /> : null}`

P.S.

Decided to put an answer here, even though probably it's too late

Faced same problem lately, aimed to change from `v2` to `v4`, spent couple hours, trying to solve it by myself (but, obviously, it was in the docs, silly me), hope this would be helpful

Comment: I've used this approach but found that everytime I open modal the underlying component is rerendered, is there a way to avoid this? (Rerender of a list of images):) of course closing modal is trigerring the same rerender.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela interesting question, looks like when the action is going through react-router's components it's re-renders all the stuff

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela is the performance impacted badly or you just interested?

Comment: Interested rather;) however I’ve noticed when images have default image applied through onError handler and there is networks issue causing fallback image to be unavailable it falls in infinite loop and all flickers.

Answer (score 5):

### Overview

Using the [react router modal example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery), [here is a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-modal-gallery-v7kl0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) I put together.

### How it works

What we wanted was to have a nested route, which could have a modal opened on it, and we wanted that modal to have a route. So, we solved this by having *multiple* `path`s for the "gallery" route - one for the gallery itself and the other for the modal.

Then, we'd just have an additional `<Route>` for the modal itself. This allows for deep-linking *directly* to the modal itself (while making sure the gallery loads in the background) *and* navigating to the modal *from* the gallery.

```
<div>
    <Switch location={background || location}>
        <Route exact path="/" children={<Home />} />
        {/* The key is to have multiple paths here */}
        <Route path={["/gallery", "/img/:id"]} children={<Gallery />} />
    </Switch>

    <Route path="/img/:id" children={<Modal />} />
</div>
```