# Open Modal by URL in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my **home page**, i have a **modal button** ([Demo](https://z6e3c.csb.app)).

With the react-router-dom, how can open modal by url without changing ui in previous page ?

**App.js**:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <h2>Click on Home</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/:id" children={<Child />} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var x = document.getElementById("counter");
    var counter = 1;
    setInterval(function() {
      counter++;
      x.innerHTML = counter;
    }, 1000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div id="counter">0</div>
        <ShowModal />
      </>
    );
  }
}

function ShowModal() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="d-buttons">
        <Link
          to="/open-modal"
          class="btn btn-danger border-0 mt-1"
          onClick={handleShow}
        >
          Show Modal
        </Link>
      </div>
      <Modal
        size="lg"
        show={show}
        onHide={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="my-lg-modal"
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="my-lg-modal">Modal</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Example Content</Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

I've also created a simple counter to prove that the home page hasn't changed.

If you not understand my issues, i will explain **clearly**:

I need to open simple bootstrap modal with the url using react-router-dom, and i dont need to change anything in my home page. because when i open a modal with link, my previous page will be gone.

Also, when i hint close button, the browser url must change to previous location.

Edit on Demo :
https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-sinoussi-z6e3c

Comment: I finded  my question in here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267588/url-based-modal-in-react-router-v4


Thanks to everyone who helped me in this topic. very thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL based modal in react-router V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267588/url-based-modal-in-react-router-v4)